# How to set webMathematica so to get PNG images and not gif

Tags: webmathematica, png-format

As the questions says, I want to set webMathematica so all generated images (for instance MSPFormat[something, TraditionalForm] or MSPShow[Plot[Cos[x],{x,-4,4}]] are PNG and not GIF. The final goal is to set transparency for such images because the web site has a background.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Edit in your favorite editor (vi or whatever) 
webMathematica/WEB-INF/Applications/MSP/MSP.m 
and change GIF to PNG nearly everywhere.

Restart webMathematica and things should just work.

Comment: that's very useful, thanks a lot. Now it works, at least for what I need right now, so that's the solution for me. However, my concern is that many other things can be done as customization of webMathematica behavior, but are not well (or not at all) documented, and require changes in system files (like the MSP.m). What I think is that webMathematica is a very powerful tool but it's very hard to discover that. Anyhow, thanks again for the solution.